# Android, Xamarin: Load Pictures Into Recycle Viewer While Scrolling

Tags: android, xamarin

Have you ever been going through apps like 9gag, Instagram or Facebook? You notice, that while scrolling the pictures load into the recviewer. They sort of come in one by one while you can still use the app.

I have implemented my own custom recviewer and am stuck right here:

```
            pictures = KumulosHelper.Pictures.getNewestXPhotosFromUserInRange
                (strUsername, "6", startNumberOfTask.ToString(), "1");



        foreach (var picture in pictures)
        {
            startNumberOfTask++;

            var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;

            lstData.Add(new DataForProfile()
            {
                imageId = startNumberOfTask,
                img = (Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap
                (KumulosGeneral.DecodePhotoFromBase64(picture.photo),
                metrics.WidthPixels, metrics.WidthPixels, true)),
                description = picture.taskId.ToString()
            });


        }
```

Where I type in "6" is where I get 6 pictures to load into my recycle viewer form the server. I can type in 10 or 20 and it continues loading those pictures. So, I could probably set up a  "reachedbottomevent" to continue loading new pictures when the viewer reached the end. But that would mean that the user has to wait everytime he or she reached the bottom of the matrix. This is pretty annoying. Also, the whole activity wont start untill all pictures are fully loaded.

How do I get my recview to behave like the afforementioned apps above? Some sort of "smart" loading the pictures?

Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Picasso library which is very reliable and easy to use. It also loads pictures in a background thread.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Square.Picasso/

> Also, the whole activity won't start until all pictures are fully loaded.

In order not to block your UI thread try using a BackgroundWorker or a Task.

At last, if you want to load a new batch of images before the user reaches the bottom of your list, then change your logic to trigger the call for a new batch for example when the user scrolls half the table.

Comment: HI and thanks: So could I write a method that downloads something in the bacjground and then displays it? how would that go ?

Comment: If you can create a URL for the image you want to display then give that URL to Picasso and it will handle all the async work for you.
Generally speaking, I think you should take a look at how to use BackgroundWorkers and Tasks. Xamarin site can give you quite nice tutorials.